# Super meat boy gives black screen but sound works [Nvidia x64 12.04]

Tags: nvidia, sound, kubuntu, games

I recently purchased and redeemed the latest humble indie bundle through the USC.  All of the games that I've tested so far work great (I've already beaten bastion).  I can launch super meat boy, but it only makes my screen turn black and I can hear the game sounds.

I have a nvidia 560 using the latest proprietary drivers and x provided by the x-swat repository.  This is on kubuntu 12.04 and my system is entirely up to date.  If it also helps to know, I am running a dual screen setup and most games seem to fullscreen to both monitors (as one big desktop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution.  The problem was that it was defaulting to fullscreen and that my fullscreen resolution was not a supported one.

The fix was to edit the `/usr/share/applications/supermeatboy.desktop` file and change the:

```
Exec=/opt/supermeatboy/SuperMeatBoy
```

to:

```
Exec=/opt/supermeatboy/SuperMeatBoy -windowed -1024x768
```

The list of supported resolutions is:

```
-640x480
-800x600
-1024x768
-1280x720
-1920x1080
```

Comment: Hm, does the 1280x720 resolution work for you? I can only go up to 1024x768, above that I only get a black screen in the super meat boy window (Which has the full resolution of my TwinView setup).